# Extract list from range Google Sheets

Tags: list, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, information-extraction

I have some data from workplaces with some different work areas, I need to extract a list for each workplace with their corresponding availables working areas, I have an example of some kind of attempt really close what I wanted. I use this formula but with more data will be long time to do it `=IF(D2=$G$1, "Yes", "No")`. I want to do it more automatic with some formulas but I don't know where to start.

[image]

Comment: Are you on google-sheet or excel? Seems screenshot from google-sheet. In your expected result why tickets is missing? `Movie Theather 2` has 3 work position but you shown only two.

Comment: @Harun24HR Google Sheets that is how data saved there is some missing work possitions but I just need the ones that have information as a list.

Comment: Can you please try my answer and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on below formula. Put the formula to `G1` cell then drag down as needed.

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTER($D$2:$D$16,$A$2:$A$16=F2,$D$2:$D$16<>""),""))
```

[image]